# Where store password / login-path in MariaDB (equivalent for mysql-config-editor)?

Tags: mysql, security, mariadb

We currently use MySQL 5.7 and store passwords via the [mysql-config-editor](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-config-editor.html).
It stores the login-path in an encrypted file, `.mylogin.cnf`.

MariaDB does not support this functionality ([and considers it a bad idea](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/mysql-56-security-through-complacency)).
So what is the MariaDB way of doing this?

PostgreSQL offers `~/.pgpass` for this purpose.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use an unencrypted options file. Create a new options file in your home directory, readable only by you, like this:

```
[client]
host='<your-db-host>'
port='<your-db-port>'
socket='<your-db-socket>'
database='<your-db-name>'
user='<your-db-user>'
password='<your-db-password>'
```

You can then use with a `--defaults-extra-file=` option when running one of the clients.

[Configuring MariaDB with Option Files](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/configuring-mariadb-with-option-files/)

You can create different config files for each login path you would have created.

The MariaDB team are taking the position that the obfuscated file is providing only a false sense of security so you're better off just facing up to the fact that you're placing your password in your filesystem in plaintext. If you have your file permissions configured correctly this can be an acceptable situation.

Comment: The main difference with login-path is (I guess) that credentials are bound to a client rather than a custom identifier, so you can only have a set of credentials for a given client and you need to set a given user for every client you need it from. From the security standpoint is basically the same, as the [article linked in the question](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/mysql-5-6-security-through-complacency/) explains.

Answer (score 1):

"The MariaDB team are taking the position that the obfuscated file is providing only a false sense of security so you're better off just facing up to the fact that you're placing your password in your filesystem in plaintext. "

Ease of use and eliminating pilot error where security (ie. password storage) is concerned is always a good idea.  True - credentials can be decrypted if the machine is rooted and other methods exist allowing batch script execution without broadcasting credentials, but mysql_config_editor eliminates possibility of error and provides ease of use.  Both good arguments in favor of using the tool.

Comment: But MariaDB doesn't support it so it isn't an option.

Answer (score -1):

Storing the password as you describe is no different from allowing passwordless logins from the IP of the host where the password would be stored - indeed, using a passwordless login on a host supporting SO_PEERCRED the latter is a lot more secure.

However even this still falls a long way short of best practice regarding authentication. Passwords should be typed in by users / administrators. There's lots of discussions on the internets about the best way to solve the chicken/egg problem of storing database passwords for service accounts (e.g. for a web application) but for real people as users, the password should be typed in by the user and should be kept in a place where it is secure.

The secure place might be a locked drawer, a phone application, a password safe application (like PasswordSafe, Teampass etc) or a full blown enterprise privileged access management solution like CyberArk or Osirium)

Comment: Thanks, I know. Our use case (for using .mylogin.cnf) is a web application. It is used for (unattended) restarts. So, I know about the weakness of the system (also included a link), the question is: does MariaDB offer a similar functionality?

Comment: "using a passwordless login on a host supporting SO_PEERCRED the latter is a lot more secure."

Comment: This implies that MariaDB has no such similar feature and using SO_PEERCRED is the recommended way to do it?

Comment: I can only tell you what I know. I am not aware of a 1:1 capability in MariaDB to implement what you describe. I am not aware of MySQL nor MariaDB recommending you only use specific functionality for their products.

Comment: It isn't the same as allowing passwordless login since that would allow access by any user whereas a stored password only allows access by those who can read the file.